# Nested while loop to extract text data

Tags: python

I am trying to get data from a txt file and put it into a dataframe. Text file looks something like this:

```
******************************************************************************************************************************
                                                                                                    DATE BUY:2018/05/26
****************************************************************************************************************************
STORE: DUBIDUBI                                                     SAILOR: 123456
***********************************************************************************************************************
            < CLIENT >                                                                      
NAME CLIENT                                 MEMBER TYPE                                     MEMBER NUMBER: 89101112     
ANTONY STARK                                    1
            <PRODUCTS>
NUM-PRODUCTS
    6
            < ADDRESS TO SEND>
186 FLEET STREET
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            < CLIENT >                                                                      
NAME CLIENT                                 MEMBER TYPE                                     MEMBER NUMBER: 13141516     
THOR                                            2
            <PRODUCTS>
NUM-PRODUCTS
    2
            < ADDRESS TO SEND>
1800 PENNSYLVANIA STREET
            <SERVICES>                  
NUM-SERVICE                             TYPE OF SERVICE
    64                                   DEVOLUTION
*****************************************************************************************************************************
```

I want to get a dataframe containing a list of all the clients information that were assisted by same sailor in same store.

**What does works**: below code reads the text line by line and extract the information of each line.

```
data []
    global STORE, DATE_BUY, SAILOR, CLIENT, MEMBER_NUM, NUM_PRODUCTS, ADDRESS, NUM_SERVICE, TYPE_MEMB, TYPE_SERV
    STORE = ""
    DATE_BUY = ""
    SAILOR = ""
    CLIENT = ""
    MEMBER_NUM = ""
    NUM_PRODUCTS = ""
    ADDRESS = ""
    NUM_SERVICE = ""
    TYPE_MEMB = ""
    TYPE_SERV = ""

    with open ('myfile', 'r') as txt_file:
        read_file = txt_file.readlines()
        for i in range(0, len(read_file)):
            line = read_file[i]
            z = line[0:50]
            a = line[0:9]
            b = line[0:42]
            c = line[112:132]
            d = line[0:14]
            e = line[0:14]
            dif_client = line[0:58]

                if a == " STORE":
                    STORE =  line[10:28]
                    SAILOR = line[30:45]
                elif c == " DATE BUY":
                    DATE_BUY = line[133:145]
                elif b == " NAME CLIENT"
                    nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                    CLIENT = nextline[0:57]
                    MEMBER_NUM = nextline[96:126]
                    TYPE_MEMB = nextline[79:86]
                elif d == " < ADDRESS":
                    nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                    ADDRESS = nextline[0:63]
                elif e == " < PRODUCTS":
                    nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                    NUM_PRODUCTS = nextline[0:24]
                elif f == " <SERVICES":
                    nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                    NUM_SERVICE = nextline[]
                    TYPE_SERV = nextline[]
            data.append({'Store':STORE, 'Sailor':SAILOR, 'Date_Buy':DATE_BUY, 'Client':CLIENT, 'Member_Num':MEMBER_NUM,
                        'Type_Memb':TYPE_MEMB, 'Address':ADDRESS, 'Products':NUM_PRODUCTS,'Num_Serv':NUM_SERVICE, 'Type_Serv':TYPE_SERV})
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**What does NOT works**: when using a nested while loop to extract information of each client assisted by a sailor my code simply does not end running. The code that does not work is:

```
data []
global STORE, DATE_BUY, SAILOR, CLIENT, MEMBER_NUM, NUM_PRODUCTS, ADDRESS, NUM_SERVICE, TYPE_MEMB, TYPE_SERV
STORE = ""
DATE_BUY = ""
SAILOR = ""
CLIENT = ""
MEMBER_NUM = ""
NUM_PRODUCTS = ""
ADDRESS = ""
NUM_SERVICE = ""
TYPE_MEMB = ""
TYPE_SERV = ""

with open ('myfile', 'r') as txt_file:
    read_file = txt_file.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(read_file)):
        line = read_file[i]
        z = line[0:50]
        a = line[0:9]
        b = line[0:42]
        c = line[112:132]
        d = line[0:14]
        e = line[0:14]
        dif_client = line[0:58]
        while dif_client != " < CLIENT >":
            if a == " STORE":
                STORE =  line[10:28]
                SAILOR = line[30:45]
            elif c == " DATE BUY":
                DATE_BUY = line[133:145]
            elif b == " NAME CLIENT"
                nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                CLIENT = nextline[0:57]
                MEMBER_NUM = nextline[96:126]
                TYPE_MEMB = nextline[79:86]
            elif d == " < ADDRESS":
                nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                ADDRESS = nextline[0:63]
            elif e == " < PRODUCTS":
                nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                NUM_PRODUCTS = nextline[0:24]
            elif f == " <SERVICES":
                nextline = read_file[i + 1]
                NUM_SERVICE = nextline[]
                TYPE_SERV = nextline[]
        data.append({'Store':STORE, 'Sailor':SAILOR, 'Date_Buy':DATE_BUY, 'Client':CLIENT, 'Member_Num':MEMBER_NUM,
                    'Type_Memb':TYPE_MEMB, 'Address':ADDRESS, 'Products':NUM_PRODUCTS,'Num_Serv':NUM_SERVICE, 'Type_Serv':TYPE_SERV})
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The desired output should look something like this. I know that each client information comes when the word < CLIENT > appears in text.

```
Date_buy        Store       Sailor      Client          Member_Number   Num_Products    Address_to_send     num_Service   type_serv
2018/05/26      dubidubi    123456      ANTONY STARK    89101112           6            186 FLEET STREET    
2018/05/26      dubidubi    123456      THOR            13141516           2        1800 PENNSYLVANIA STREET    64      DEVOLUTION
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: First, you haven't given us a specific problem: you've posted a wall of untested code without telling us what's wrong with it and where you're stuck.  "I do not know how to use it properly" strongly suggests that you need to return to your materials on `for` and learn to use small ones.  You also need to demonstrate that the loop body will do what you want on each type of input line.

Comment: Back up; start small.  Make a loop that simply reads and `print`s the file, line by line.  Then start processing the lines.  Make sure you can handle each field and each line properly in isolation.  Don't add a new line type until you can handle the previous ones.

Comment: Refer to your tutorial materials.  Your posted code contains a lot of superfluous code (distracting), meaningless variable names (hard to follow), and hard-coded column numbers.  Instead of this painstaking formatting, look at Python's `in` operator, and use the `split` method to extract things from the input lines.

Comment: Posting was edited

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the description.  The problem is in the infinite loop you built:

```
    dif_client = line[0:58]
    while dif_client != " < CLIENT >":
        if a == " STORE":
            ...
```

`dif_client` doesn't change within the loop.  There is no `break` or other exit, only the `while` condition (which is good design).  Therefore, once you get into the loop, you have no way to leave: `dif_client` is constant.

Your logic is incorrect: you have two loops that are trying to walk through the lines of the file:

```
    for i in range(0, len(read_file)):
        ...
        while dif_client != " < CLIENT >":
            # Process one line
```

The body of the `while` is designed to process one line.  When you're done with that, you need to go to the next iteration of the `for` to get the next line.  Finding a `CLIENT` line is a `if` decision, not a loop.